# Return non-zero exit status if a child processes fails

Tags: bash, performance, docker, continuous-integration

I have a docker build script which builds a series of libraries and runs test suits. In order to make my build script run faster on a many core server, I changed put the sequential order of commands (being passed to `RUN` to a bash invocation of several parallel commands:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c -e '\
    cmd1 arg1 & \
    cmd2 & \
    cmd3 arg1 arg2=foo arg3 & \
    wait'
```

This worked file when there was no error. Then I realized even if one of child processes return a non-zero exit status, the whole bash command returns `0` and docker continues to build... How can I make the bash call to return `0` iff all its children return `0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize that bash's wait command for specific PID returns it's return status:

```
job1 &
job1pid=$!
job2 &
job2pid=$!
job3 &
job3pid=$!
if wait ${job1pid} && wait ${job2pid} && wait ${job3pid}
then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```

Test:

```
$ cat > childprocess.sh
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN { exit('$1'); }' &
job1pid=$!
awk 'BEGIN { exit('$2'); }' &
job2pid=$!
awk 'BEGIN { exit('$3'); }' &
job3pid=$!
if wait ${job1pid} && wait ${job2pid} && wait ${job3pid}
then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi

$ ./childprocess.sh 0 0 0
$ echo $?
0
$ ./childprocess.sh 1 1 1
$ echo $?
1
$ ./childprocess.sh 0 1 0
$ echo $?
1
```

From [GNU bash doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html):

> wait [-n] [jobspec or pid …]
>
> Wait until the child process specified by each process ID pid or job
>   specification jobspec exits and return the exit status of the last
>   command waited for. If a job spec is given, all processes in the job
>   are waited for. If no arguments are given, all currently active child
>   processes are waited for, and the return status is zero. If the -n
>   option is supplied, wait waits for any job to terminate and returns
>   its exit status. If neither jobspec nor pid specifies an active child
>   process of the shell, the return status is 127.